# Use a report filter directly in power-query-result-table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

**Power-Query-Result-Table**

[image]

**Pivot-Table on Power-Query-Result-Table**

[image]

---

I am getting the list in the first screenshot as a result from the `Power-Query-Editor`. 
Now I want to apply a `Report Filter` to it. Therfore, I put the data into a `Pivot-Table`.

In general this solution is working but I am wondering if it is possible to have the `Report Fitler` directly in the `Power-Query-Result-Table` to avoid an additional `Pivot-Table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter for crew directly in the PowerQuery using the drop down atop the crew column like below image. In this image I filter for Crew=J

[image]

That generates code as follows:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Crew] = "J")
```

If you put **J** into a a cell on the excel sheet and gave that cell a range name like **CrewName**, you could reference that range name in the powerquery and filter dynamically

```
 #"Filtered Rows"= Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Crew] = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CrewName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1])
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Is there a way to automate it? At the moment I put a name in a cell and then I have to manually update the table-result to apply the filter.

Comment: I actually think your original method is the best way, but you could probably refresh the powerquery onChange in the range named cell using a small VBA. I dont do VBA well

Comment: If you have Office 365 then you could also use the FILTER() function to avoid using a pivot table. In your FILTER formula you could reference a validation dropdown list cell that has your criteria.